# Trouble understanding a specific C implementation of Merge Sort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to follow this code step by step but still I can't understand certain steps it's taking.

```
void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
             : i == m      ? a[j++]
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
             :               a[i++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);
}

void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n / 2;
    merge_sort(a, m);
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);
    merge(a, n, m);
}
```

Here's a simple example so that you can see what the issues are. It's sorting the integer array {4,3,2,1} .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
             : i == m      ? a[j++]
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
             :               a[i++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);
}

void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n / 2;
    int g;
    printf("a before merge_sort(a,m) %i\n",a);
    printf("m %i\n",m);
    printf("n %i\n",n);
    printf("\n");
    for(g=0;g<m;++g) printf("%i\n", a[g]);
    merge_sort(a, m);
    printf("a after merge_sort(a,m) %i\n",a);
    printf("m %i\n",m);
    printf("n %i\n",n);
    printf("\n");
    for(g=0;g<m;++g) printf("%i\n", a[g]);
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);
    printf("a after merge_sort(a+m, n-m) %i\n",a);
    printf("m %i\n",m);
    printf("n %i\n",n);
    printf("\n");
    for(g=0;g<m;++g) printf("%i\n",a[g]);
    merge(a, n, m);
    printf("a after merge(a,n,m) %i\n ",a);
    printf("m %i\n",m);
    printf("n %i\n",n);
    for(g=0;g<m;++g) printf("%i\n",a[g]);
}

int main(){
    int test[4] = {4,3,2,1};
    int i;
    merge_sort(&test[0],4);
    printf("\nFinal result:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;++i){
        printf("%i ",test[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And here's the output.

```
Begin of if
End of if(no return)

a before merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcebc
m 2
n 4

4
3

Begin of if
End of if(no return)

a before merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcebc
m 1
n 2

4

Begin of if

a after merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcebc
m 1
n 2

4

Begin of if

a after merge_sort(a+m, n-m) 0xbfadcebc
m 1
n 2

4

a after merge(a,n,m) 0xbfadcebc
 m 1
n 2

3

a after merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcebc
m 2
n 4

3
4

Begin of if
End of if(no return)

a before merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcec4
m 1
n 2

2

Begin of if

a after merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcec4
m 1
n 2

2

Begin of if

a after merge_sort(a+m, n-m) 0xbfadcec4
m 1
n 2

2

a after merge(a,n,m) 0xbfadcec4
 m 1
n 2

1

a after merge_sort(a+m, n-m) 0xbfadcebc
m 2
n 4

3
4

a after merge(a,n,m) 0xbfadcebc
 m 2
n 4

1
2

Final result:
1 2 3 4
```

This is what's puzzling me:

```
Begin of if

a after merge_sort(a+m, n-m) 0xbfadcebc
m 1
n 2

4

a after merge(a,n,m) 0xbfadcebc
 m 1
n 2

3
```

I'd expect a+m to change the address of a from 0xbfadcebc to something else, but it simply produces the number 4 as an output again. It's as if merge(a+m,n-m) didn't have any effect and produced the same as if I had written merge(a,n-m).

Furthermore, merge(a,n,m) is not a recursive function, so I'd just expect the function to end after running it.
I don't get how this:

```
a after merge_sort(a,m) 0xbfadcebc
m 2
n 4

3
4
```

...can be the next step after merge(a,n,m).

Comment: Your code is full of single-letter var names and 'clever' use of nested ternary operators and indexing.  I suggest that you make the code readable with intermediate variables etc, then step through with your debugger, making vary careful note of the var values at each step.  It's very hard and exacting work.  It's better if you do it. If a page of code looks like a mess at first glance, I don't bother going through it - it's too much grunt work.

Answer (score 1):

Commented code:

```
/* a = ptr to sub-array */
/* 0 = starting index */
/* m = mid point index */
/* n = ending index */
/* left  half indices = 0 to m-1 */
/* right half indices = m to n   */
void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int)); /* allocate temp array */
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]    /* if end of right, copy left */
             : i == m      ? a[j++]    /* if end of left, copy right */
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]    /* if right < left, copy right */
             :               a[i++];   /* else (left <= right), copy left */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {          /* copy x[] back into a[] */
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);                           /* free temp array */
}

/* a = ptr to sub-array */
/* n = size == ending index of sub-array */     
void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)                         /* if < 2 elements nothing to do */
        return;
    int m = n / 2;                     /* m = mid point index */
    merge_sort(a, m);                  /* sort a[0] to a[m-1] */
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);          /* sort a[m] to a[n-1] */
    merge(a, n, m);                    /* merge the two halves */
}
```